# Where am I supposed to get Winter Cherry and other transmutation ingredients?

Tags: the-witcher-3, the-witcher-3-blood-and-wine

I am playing Witcher 3 Blood and Wine and have transmutation recipe to change `Greater Green mutagens` that are plentiful to `Greater Red mutagens`...

However transmutation recipe requires `Winter Cherry`. I have been going through all herbalists and alchemy suppliers in expansion and old game and no one seem to gave them...

**Where am I supposed to get Winter Cherries?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It turns out that you need to grow them in your vineyard

First you will need to upgrade your house it will cost 5000
then you need to wait for 3 days
Then you need to upgrade your garden that will be another 2000
then wait for another two days

Then when you exit the house run left across the spring and there will be a shed with rare plants inside.

I have also made youtube video as it is not obvious....